# How to use A HREF with $_POST?

Tags: php, html, post

I have an HTML menu with links like `<a href="input&db=<some database>"`  There are multiple menu items and multiple databases, so I am using GET as my form method and using it in my menu item links.

However, that shows up in the browser's address bar (as /inout&db=mydatabase) & might lead the user to start guessing as to database names.

How can I have a list of links to the same page, in which only the database varies, using $_POST ?

---

EDIT:  oops, my bad Shoulda said server-side only, so no JS

Comment: No JS => Not gonna happen. Only possibility is to submit a `<form method="post">` so either JS to tie a `<a>` element to the form *or* use the submit button instead (styled as a link).

Comment: You could use forms and style the submit buttons as links via CSS.

Comment: @Gordon (+1) can you elaborate on that?

Comment: there is not much to elaborate. You just write a regular form with some input fields and a regular submit button. Then you use CSS to make it look as closely to a regular link as possible, e.g. set background-color to transparent and remove the borders and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST values will be just as obvious to anyone who would be savvy enough to do anything with this information. Unless you're building something like phpMyAdmin, you should never pass such internal information to the client side to begin with. And if you are, where's the harm? You do have proper authentication in place, don't you?

Comment: +1 but - how many are that savvy?  All I need is just good enough to prevent those who might vote T-party

Comment: @Mawg Well, why are you asking then? ;-) It's really not about how big the chance of a savvy person taking an interest in your site is, you simply architect your application in a secure fashion from the ground up, always, full stop. I like to think in terms of *"If there's a chance something can go wrong, it will eventually."*

Comment: @Mawg While I understand that, that's a terrible excuse (for a company; get more money if it takes more time). Try adopting a framework like CakePHP or CodeIgniter, this can drastically cut down your development time while already having a stable foundation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to send request via post using links is to use JavaScript. But sending it via post is not secure at all; anyone can install FireBug to see the request.

Instead, I'll suggest a change to your design. Databases are usually at the bottom tier in an application hierarchy, and coupling page details with database sounds unnecessary. Maybe you should try to encapsulate pages so that they don't need to know which database they are reading from?

Granted, I have no idea of the scope of your application (you may be doing something like phpmyadmin). Then it may be unavoidable, and I will just suggest the usual combination of verification and sanctification all users' input and their rights.

Or you can just encrypt your database names. Still I would prefer a change to design.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onclick` event of the anchors to submit a hidden POST form, or to perform AJAX POST actions.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are a few narrow and dangerous solutions you can apply:

- Use an iframe : everything will work as before, but the actual address will not appear in the browser address bar.
- Use AJAX to fetch data.
- Replace the link with a form-submitting button or `javascript:` link.

These all solve the "database name appears in address bar" issue, however:

- Anyone with even basic technical skills and appropriate tools (chrome, firebug) can determine the database name anyway by looking at the requests being sent out.
- Not using GET can mess up the browser's back and refresh buttons, and prevent deep linking.

My suggestion would be to keep using GET as you currently are, but add a secret token to the URL (such as `HMAC(db_name,secret_key)`) that cannot be guessed by the user but can be easily checked for validity by the server. This way, unless you give the user a link to the database (with both database name and secret token), all the guessing in the world will not let them access it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither GET or POST will hide your database name.
Even you using POST, view source will reveal the HTML.

In the first place, you should not expose your database name.

Or replace it with some fuzzy mapping

such as

```
input&db=A
input&db=B
```

Internally, do string matching and convert`A` to actual database name

Comment: The `db=A|B|...` is pretty transparent, IMO. Security by (semi-)obscurity should not be the solution here.

Comment: +1 Gotcha ... errm, Gotme!! I forgot view source, coz it's late Friday here. KK, will leave it as GET and just validate the input